# Python script to copy n files to another folder

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I'm looking for a python script that would took for example first 5000 files and copy them to another folder. Then after another run, it would took next 5000 files and copy them.

I tried using `shutil` but couldn't make it work, no matter what I tried.

Can you please help, or guide me on the right direction?

Comment: What went wrong?  That is what you should use

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: My recommendation when moving/copying/deleting: Start by printing the origin path and destination path in one line. Then move on to doing the operation. Show us the code! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is a combination of  os.walk() [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and shutil.copy() [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html)

Building a script based on sample provided on those two links looks pretty straight forward.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you read the code for help to make it work Change the Mkv format to whatever you want

it's a python script you can use crontab for Linux or Microsoft windows schedule tool if you need any help just reply

```
import os
import json

SRC_FOLDER = '/home/SOURCE /'
DEST_FOLDER = '/home/Destination folder /'

def read_data():
    with open('/home/PATH TO the json file.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data

def write_data(added_files, uploaded_files):
    with open('/home/PATH TO the json file.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(added_files+uploaded_files, f)

def main():
    all_downloads = os.listdir(SRC_FOLDER)
    all_uploads = read_data()
    added_files = []
    for file_name in all_downloads:
        if file_name not in all_uploads:
            if "mkv" == file_name.split(".")[-1]:
                print file_name.split('.')[-1]
                added_files.append(file_name)
                file = open(DEST_FOLDER+file_name, 'wb')
                with open(SRC_FOLDER+file_name, 'rb') as f:
                    while True:
                        byte = f.read(20480)
                        if not byte:
                            break
                        file.write(byte)
    write_data(added_files, all_uploads)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

iCODEiT 0UT